# How do I resolve error, "(IM002) [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified"?

Tags: asp.net, sql, visual-studio-2012, odbc, toad

How do I resolve error, "(IM002) [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified" ?

So far I have tried:

1. Adding the right conenction string
2. Make sure the referencing DSN that has been created

What are some more things I should look into?

online materials mostly only revolve around those two but they haven't helped.

Stack Trace:

```
[OdbcException (0x80131937): ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified]
   System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.HandleError(OdbcHandle hrHandle, RetCode retcode) +1247198
   System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnectionHandle..ctor(OdbcConnection connection, OdbcConnectionString constr, OdbcEnvironmentHandle environmentHandle) +95
   System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnectionOpen..ctor(OdbcConnection outerConnection, OdbcConnectionString connectionOptions) +53
   System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject) +55
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +22
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +38
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +5368242
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +146
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +16
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) +17
   System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.Open() +42
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +121
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +316
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, String srcTable) +86
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments) +1481
   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) +21
   DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.Internal.DataHelper.PerformSelect() +217
   DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.GridViewDataHelper.PerformSelect() +285
   DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.Internal.DataContainer.PerformSelect() +74
   DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxDataWebControlBase.DataBindCore() +12
   DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxDataWebControlBase.DataBindInternal() +123
   DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxWebControl.DataBind() +37
   DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.ASPxGridView.DataBind() +207
   DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.Internal.DataHelperBase.EnsureDataBound(Boolean ensureChildControls) +93
   DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.Internal.DataContainer.EnsureDataBound() +78
   DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxDataWebControlBase.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +21
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +83
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +974
```

edit: just added the stack trace

Comment: let's start with the code....  is there a stack trace?

Comment: System or user DSN? My habitual solution to ODBC DSN problems is never to use them... Oh and what are you connecting to through ODBC?

Comment: @Tony it's user DSN. I am connecting to SQL/Express. I am new to ASP.net, sorry if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Why are you using ODBC to connect to SQL Express??? That's barmy, you lose a whole swathe of functionality. Given that then, you need to make sure the account that the IIS service is running as, is the user the DSN is for at a guess. Should be using SQLConnection, Command etc, and pulling the connection string from the config. Loads of examples about.